# Drawing an event that moves you, do you still do tile text?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

For example, I just discovered the Attic, which states:

> When exiting, you must attempt a Speed roll of 3+. If you fail, lose 1 Might

Now I draw [The Left Hand](https://fsmedia.imgix.net/a9/6a/10/7e/2a8a/476c/a82c/475bf1ccbbe8/the-left-hand-is-situational-but-handy-when-youve-got-something-to-replace-what-you-cut-off.jpeg) as the event card for this room,  and choose this option:

> Keep your hand. Lose 2 Sanity, gain 1 Might, and move to the nearest room with an Omen symbol and draw an omen card.

Do I still have to make the Attic's speed roll to go to the nearest room?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you must always roll for the bad stuff that can happen to you for leaving a room, no matter how or why you are leaving the room.

From the official FAQ (which for some reason stopped being linked on the Wizards/Avalon Hill websites with the release of Widow's Walk):

> **Attic, Graveyard, Junk Room, Pentagram Chamber -- If something like the Mystic Slide causes you to leave one of these rooms involuntarily, do you still make a roll?**
>
> Yes. You roll no matter what causes you to leave.

Comment: This is a great find. Do you know whether there's a publically accessible version of this FAQ online anywhere, and if so, could you provide the link?

Comment: I wonder how this works with the rule that says that if you fail the roll, you can choose to stay where you are and not take damage? Those rules seem contradictory...

Comment: @TheThirdMan I have looked, there is no publicly accessible link I could find to the version I have, nor do any of the old links work either.  There is this older version of the file on BGG which does include the ruling: https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/12137/betrayal-faq-bookletpdf

Comment: @GendoIkari I have always treated it as a case of book rules vs. card rules, and the Betrayal rulebook explicitly states that card rules trump book rules. Thus the card says you move, so you have to move.

Answer (score 1):

Ken has already stated the rules, but I just want to give another way to think about this. A lot of the game is up to interpretation, so I usually role play as much as possible and go by what seems logical even if it sometimes goes against the rules.

If you're trying to get out of the junk room, then go ahead and make a might role to push junk out of your way as you leave the room. But if you're falling out of a room, or being pulled out by the walls, it doesn't really make sense to *push junk out of your way per se*.

Sometimes it's just best to go with what seems logical and role play it up.

Comment: This would though technically be a house rule, since the rules do cover the situation and tell you you need to make the roll.